# How do I restrict access to specific database user accounts in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, access-control

I'd like to be able to either restrict access to specific database user accounts, or block specific database user accounts from logging in via phpMyAdmin.  How can I configure phpMyAdmin to do this?

Specifically, I'm running phpMyAdmin Ubuntu server.  I want to know how to configure this at the level of phpMyAdmin **itself**, and **not** through the webserver or OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To configure phpMyAdmin, you need to find your `config.inc.php` configuration file.  On Ubuntu, this is located in `/etc/phpmyadmin`.  Edit this file.

Add lines to this file **after** the block that ends with `$i++`.

### To deny access to all users by default, and then allow specific users:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'explicit';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = [
    'allow alex from all'
];
```

### To allow access to all users by default, and then deny specific users:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'deny,allow';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = [
    'deny alex from all'
];
```

You can replace `all` with patterns to match specific IP addresses or ranges of addresses.  See the full documentation at the [phpMyAdmin docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_AllowDeny_order).

Comment: Should be added immediately *before* the `$i++;`  surely??